# Multiple bar charts on one axis in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

So I have a bunch of series laid out like this in excel:
[image: chart data]

I'd like to have them plotted all on one column chart but with the series separated (i.e. not clustered) so it basically is several column charts stuck together that share the same y-axis.

Like this but combined only one actual chart:
[image: chart]

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very easy to make a chart like this in Excel.  You'll just need to change your data layout.

1. List all of your category labels are in a single column.
2. Create a column for each category type (e.g. equities, corporate, sovreign...)
3. For each category, just place the value in the appropriate categories column. Your data should look something like this:

   [image: Data Layout]
4. Then, create a Clustered Column Chart `Insert>Column>Clustered Column`.
5. Select your data series, then `Format>Series Option>Series Overlap` and set the value to 100%.
6. Format to taste (e.g. move horizontal axis to low, remove grid lines, adjust percentage decimals to 0, etc...)

Your completed chart should look something like this:

[image: MultiColumn]

FWIW, I'd consider a Bar Chart laid out in similar fashion (just insert Clustered Bar instead of Clustered Column). Cleaned up a bit, it would make your category labels easier to read (horizontal, rather than vertical) and can be compressed a bit easier into a smaller space.

[image: MultiBar]

Comment: Nicely answered.